# Openshift and Artifactory integration error

Tags: docker, openshift-origin

I am unable to pull docker images from artifactory on openshift origin.
But i am able to pull same images from server using docker pull.

Error :

Internal error occurred: Get https://artifactory.mycompany.net/v2/: Bad Gateway?

Note: I have enabled proxy and gave no proxy to my org servers in openshift master config file.

I have also added artifactory docker repo as insecure registry in docker configuration

--

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open shift don't take wildcard entry in noproxy. So by providing full name in no_proxy got fixed